# Cast between generic collections

Tags: c#, generics, collections

In the following example, why can't I cast `collectionA` to `collectionB` given that the compiler knows that a `TItem` is a `A<T>`?

```
public class A<T>
{
}

public void Foo<TItem, T> () where TItem : A<T>
{
    var collectionA = new List<TItem>();
    var collectionB = (List<A<T>>)collectionA; // "Cannot cast" error here
}
```

Comment: Search for "covariance" and "contravariance"

Comment: Why do you make it generic in the first place? IF TItem is always A<T>

Comment: Have a look at this FAQ on Covariance and Contravariance. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reading suggestions - very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that it would allow you to place inappropriate items into collectionA.

Here's a simplified reworking of it, which hopefully makes it easier to see the problem:

Suppose you have (pseudocode):

```
class Animal {...}

class Dog: Animal { Bark(){} }

class Cat: Animal { Meow(){} }
```

Now imagine you could do this:

```
var dogs = new List<Dog>();

dogs.Add(new Dog());

dogs[0].Bark();

var animals = (List<Animal>) dogs;
```

Then you would be able to do this:

```
animals.Add(new Animal()); // Adds an Animal to the list 'dogs', which 'animals' references.

dogs[1].Bark(); // dogs will now have two elements, but the second isn't a dog -
                // so calling Bark() will explode.
```

Comment: thanks of course that makes sense now. I've got some code smell to get rid of now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you're instructing the system to convert from `List<X>` to `List<Y>` rather than saying that you want to cast each item within the list from `X` to `Y`.

You can do this though:

```
public class A<T>
{
}

public void Foo<TItem, T>() where TItem : A<T>
{
    var collectionA = new List<TItem>();
    var collectionB = new List<A<T>>(collectionA.ToArray()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use either

```
var collectionB = collectionA.OfType<List<A<T>>>();
```

or

```
var collectionB = collectionA.Cast<List<A<T>>>();
```

The first will ignore anything that's not of type `List<A<T>>` and can't be treated as it.  The second will throw an exception if there's something in the list which can't be converted.